# Clean Architecture with Screen having BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart, clean-architecture

I'm using clean architecture for my Flutter App. I am creating a screen `HomeScreen` which has a `BottomNavigationBar`, and in this screen I need to import multiple screens from different features.

The file structure of my project is:

```
lib
|- features
   |- feature_1
      |- data
      |- domain
      |- presentation
         |- controllers
         |- screens
            |- screen_1.dart
            |- screen_2.dart
         |- widgets
   |- feature_2
      |- data
      |- domain
      |- presentation
         |- controllers
         |- screens
            |- screen_1.dart
            |- screen_2.dart
         |- widgets
   |- feature_3
      |- data
      |- domain
      |- presentation
         |- controllers
         |- screens
            |- screen_1.dart
            |- screen_2.dart
         |- widgets

|- shared (basically core)
   |- constants
   |- widgets
   |- functions
```

My `HomeScreen` would look something like this:

#### HomeScreen.dart

```
import 'feature_1/presentation/screens/screen_1.dart';
import 'feature_2/presentation/screens/screen_1.dart';
import 'feature_3/presentation/screens/screen_1.dart';
import 'feature_4/presentation/screens/screen_1.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: index,
        children: const [
          Feature1Screen(),
          Feature2Screen(),
          Feature3Screen(),
          Feature4Screen(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationWidget(
        index: index,
        onIndexTap: onTap,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Multiple approaches:

1. Creating a separate feature for this screen. It will directly import screens from other features.
2. Moving the screens, being accessed by `BottomNavigationBar`, from different features to a new single feature. Basically **Point 1** but screens moved together.
3. Creating features folder in shared (core) folder and adding `HomeScreen` in that folder.

### Problems:

1. The problem with the first approach is that it clearly breaks the rules of clean architecture.
2. The second approach removes the main screens from the features and combines them in single feature. I feel this approach leaves the features incomplete/semi-complete.
3. This approach seems valid to me.

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What rule do you think is broken? Clean architecture talks about dependencies, not file locations; in all cases the `HomeScreen` depends on the `FeatureXScreen`s. Moving the files around won't fundamentally change that. The features are closer to the domain than 'chrome' such as navigation bars, so everything should be pointing inward.

Comment: Thanks, @PeteKirkham, cleared a lot of confusions